# How to prevent display: flex from removing whitespaces in the text

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
span {
  background-color: red;
}

.only-whitespace {
  display: inline-flex;
  white-space: pre;
}

.trailing-whitespace {
  display: inline-flex;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
only whitespace: <span class="only-whitespace"> </span>
<br/>
trailing whitespace: <span class="trailing-whitespace"> a </span>
```

As you can see in the example above, flexbox element with `white-space: pre` style keeps trailing whitespaces but doesn't keep standalone whitespaces. I want to keep these whitespaces also, without setting `width` property or something. Do we have any way to achieve that?

Comment: why you need flex to start with? you should never make a text container a flexbox container (related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56697561/8620333)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that you can without modifying the "only-whitespace" to include some sort of non-whitespace character, such as `&nbsp;`.

According to [the W3C definition of flexible box items](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items):

> ...if the entire sequence of child text runs contains only white space (i.e. characters that can be affected by the white-space property) it is instead not rendered (just as if its text nodes were display:none).